# Linear Riemann-Hilbert problems in multiply-connected domains

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Hello,

I am looking for a reference giving the solution of the linear Riemann-Hilbert problem in multiply-connected domains of C. Many authors refer to Gakhov's book, but the presentation is quite confusing. Do you know a more modern reference for this ?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a few papers around, see, for example:

Matrix Riemann–Hilbert problems and factorization on Riemann surfaces

Câmara, dos Santos & dos Santos

Journal of Functional Analysis 255 (2008) 228–254

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers!
Best regards.
Toccata